# Using UITableViewController and Cell with Parse

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, parse-platform

I've been following this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q6qcrO8uNzU&feature=youtu.be). Below is the code that is produced at the end. However, for `getShifts.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects:AnyObject[]!, error:NSError!) -> Void in`

I get an error that says I should put `AnyObject[]!` like `[AnyObject]!`...but that just creates more errors. Any ideas?

```
 import UIKit

class AvailableShifts: UITableViewController {

var shiftData: NSMutableArray!

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)

    loadData()

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 2//shiftData.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:AvailableShiftsCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as AvailableShiftsCell

    let shift: PFObject = shiftData.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as PFObject

    cell.shiftLabel.text = shift.objectForKey("Shift") as String

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell
}


/*
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return true
}
*/

/*
// Override to support editing the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .Delete {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    } else if editingStyle == .Insert {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }    
}
*/

/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath fromIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {

}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return true
}
*/

/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

func loadData () {

    shiftData.removeAllObjects()

    var getShifts = PFQuery(className: "Shifts")

    getShifts.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects:AnyObject[]!, error:NSError!) -> Void in

        if (error == nil) {

            for object: PFObject! in objects {

                self.shiftData.addObject(object)
            }

            let array: NSArray = self.shiftData.reverseObjectEnumerator().allObjects

            self.shiftData = array as NSMutableArray

            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

    }

}

}
```

Comment: Not sure what the question exactly is but if xcode has generated a suggestion based on your implementation it's probably in your best interests to heed that suggestion and trouble shoot through the remaining errors presented. What exactly are the errors after you insert the correct syntax for AnyObject? Review [HERE](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html) for what [AnyObject] is actually doing. Search for NSArray

Answer (score 0):

Try the following,
First change at the Top `var shiftData: NSMutableArray!` to `var shiftData = [PFObject]()`

and your func loadData()

```
func loadData () {

    var getShifts = PFQuery(className: "Shifts")

    getShifts.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
    if error == nil {

    var shiftData = objects as [PFObject]
    self.shiftData = shiftData
    var lastIndex = NSIndexPath(forRow: self.shiftData.count - 1, inSection: 0)

  }
 }
}
```

and at cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell" as AvailableShiftsCell
    let shift = self.shiftData[indexPath.row]
        cell.shiftLabel.text = shift as String

    return cell
}
```

Hope that helped.